# How to iterate on multi-level JSON in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops

Goal:
Iterate over a sub-json looking in 2 keys for a specific string

In PHP it's easy but for python 3, I cannot seems to find a proper way. I tried other solutions I found on the web but I always end up getting an error.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "main1": {
    "sub1": {
      "prop1": "name1",
      "prop2": "name2"
    },
    "sub2": {
      "prop1": "name1",
      "prop2": "name2"
    },
  },
  "main2": {
    "sub1": {
      "prop1": "name1",
      "prop2": "name2"
    },
    "sub2": {
      "prop1": "name1",
      "prop2": "name2"
    },
  },
}
```

Code

```
self.data = dataIO.load_json('data/data.json')

for item in self.data['main1'].items():
  if item['prop1'] == 'name1' or item['prop2'] == 'name1':
    print 'found one'
```

Error:
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

items() returns tuple of key-value, so you either have to use item[1]['prop1']:

```
for item in x['main1'].items():
  if item[1]['prop1'] == 'name1' or item[1]['prop2'] == 'name1':
    print 'found one'
```

Or better, make it this way:

```
self.data = dataIO.load_json('data/data.json')

for key,item in self.data['main1'].items():
  if item['prop1'] == 'name1' or item['prop2'] == 'name1':
    print 'found one'
```

Comment: I remember I tried something like that, but it must not been the same because this is working. Fantastic, I owe you a cookie! :) (I'll accept this answer in 7 minutes cannot accept earlier) - I took the second example